# Define custom property sets (with Add-Member?) for use in Select-Object

Tags: powershell, custom-object, pscustomobject

What I try to do is quite simple: create a custom object with some properties, and then define "groups" of properties (columns) for use in Select-Object.  Let me clarify:

```
$props = @{"Mary"=1;"Jane"=2;"Frank"=3;"John"=5;"Brenda"=6}
$obj = New-Object PSObject $props
```

I now have a custom object with some bogus data.  What I now want to be able to do is

```
$obj | select Male
$obj | select Female
```

And what I had thought would do the trick, is something like this:

```
$obj | Add-Member PropertySet "Male" @("Frank","John")
$obj | Add-Member PropertySet "Female" @("Mary","Jane","Brenda")
```

It doesn't work - I get this error:

```
Add-Member : Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type 
"System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.String]".
```

I guess I should provide another object type than my array to `Add-Member`, but I'm unsure how I should do that.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Important note: I'm on Powershell 2, and I read on various sites that it has a bug that doesn't allow setting the default properties.  That's not what I want to do - I want to create a custom property set and not a default one - but it could be that this bug also prevents me from getting what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are very close. The problem is that you're not creating the object correctly. You need to specify the `-Property` parameter before you specify a hashtable of properties. Without it, you just create a hashtable. This works:

```
$props = @{"Mary"=1;"Jane"=2;"Frank"=3;"John"=5;"Brenda"=6}
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props

$obj | Add-Member PropertySet "Male" @("Frank","John")
$obj | Add-Member PropertySet "Female" @("Mary","Jane","Brenda")

$obj | select male

Frank John
----- ----
    3    5
```

Why did this happend? 
If you read the syntax for `New-Object` using `Get-help new-object` or `Get-Command New-Object -Syntax`, you will see that for normal .Net types, the syntax is:

```
New-Object [-TypeName] <String> [[-ArgumentList] <Object[]>] [-Property <IDictionary>]
```

Notice that `-ArgumentList` is the 2nd paramter, not `-Property` as you expected. So your code actually did:

```
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -ArgumentList $props
```

instead of:

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $props
```

**EDIT** The solution above only worked in PS3.0 . It's still valid though, as the `-Property` parameter is required in PS2.0 also. In PS2.0 you need to cast the propertyset-array to `string[]` (string-array) and not an object-array (`object[]`) which is the default array. A complete solution for PS2.0 is:

```
$props = @{"Mary"=1;"Jane"=2;"Frank"=3;"John"=5;"Brenda"=6}
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props

$obj | Add-Member PropertySet "Male" ([string[]]@("Frank","John"))
$obj | Add-Member PropertySet "Female" ([string[]]@("Mary","Jane","Brenda"))

$obj | select male

Frank John
----- ----
    3    5
```

Comment: Graimer, your answer is complete, detailed, to the point and more than I even asked for. You made my day!  It works perfect now.
It's a pity I can't vote twice on your answer :)

Comment: Your kind comment is more than enough :-)